# rosdep *_python3 style rules

Tags: ros, ros2, rosdep, python3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [rosdep contribution guide](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) points out:

> You may see existing rules that use _python3-suffixed distribution codenames. These were trialed as a possible style of Python 3 rules and should not be used for newly added definitions.

I just ran into one, and I'm not sure how to utilize it. I'm talking about [python-serial](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/rosdep/python.yaml#L4028). There seems to  be no way to get rosdep to resolve the `python-serial` key to the `python3-serial` Debian package. I'm running with ROS 2 Dashing on Ubuntu Bionic, and I've tried the following combinations:

```
$ rosdep resolve python-serial
#apt
python-serial
$ ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=3 rosdep resolve python-serial
#apt
python-serial
$ rosdep resolve python3-serial
ERROR: no rosdep rule for 'python3-serial'
```

_python3-suffixed rules sound deprecated, but at least in practice they actually appear dead. Is there a special way to use these of which I'm unaware, or should we be rewriting such rules to be python3-* top-level rules alongside the python-* ones, as is the now-established practice for new rules?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343842/rosdep-*_python3-style-rules/) by [kyrofa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20478/kyrofa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 347 on 2020-02-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is there a special way to use these of which I'm unaware

The way to use those is to tell rosdep that your OS is "*_python3"
e.g.

```
root@cdf6f1d3bd1c:/# rosdep resolve python-serial
#apt
python-serial
root@cdf6f1d3bd1c:/# rosdep resolve python-serial --os ubuntu:bionic_python3
#apt
python3-serial
```

> should we be rewriting such rules to be python3-* top-level rules alongside the python-* ones, as is the now-established practice for new rules?

I believe yes, you would need to use a conditional dependency similarly to https://github.com/ros/ros/blob/ee5469facade6ff917d56ea9340b7c5a90f8f574/core/roslib/package.xml#L31-L32

Note that you will also need to [add a `python3-serial` key to the rosdep database](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#rosdep-rules-contributions) as it doesn't currently exist

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2020-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kyrofa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20478/kyrofa/) on 2020-02-11**:
Oh wow, I didn't even think about trying a different os! In that case, I see no downside to adding the new rule as well. Thank you!

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2020-02-11**:
That approach is explicitly discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> These were trialed as a possible style of Python 3 rules and should not be used for newly added definitions.

You simply shouldn'y use these rules.

Instead your package should declare different conditional dependencies for Python 2 and Python 3. See http://wiki.ros.org/UsingPython3/SourceCodeChanges#Conditional_Dependencies for an example as well as http://wiki.ros.org/UsingPython3 for the high level documentation regarding the transition to Python 3 support.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2020-02-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kyrofa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20478/kyrofa/) on 2020-02-13**:
You might consider adding such guidance to the rosdep contribution guide; it was unclear if I should go ahead with adding a top-level rule or figure out how to use the existing _python ones. The only thing that was clear was that I shouldn't be writing NEW _python ones.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2020-02-13**:
Please consider to contribute a pull request if you would like the documentation to see improved.

**Comment by [kyrofa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20478/kyrofa/) on 2020-02-13**:
Of course: https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/23761